# Custom Overlay Grid - Labeling the axes differently

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, overlay, grids-graticules

i have a map where i want to put the grid axes. i have a separate layer based on which i want to create the axes. now custom overlay feature in arcGIS gives you only one label field to label the axes but i have 2 columns based on which i want to showcase the X and Y axes labels.

How do i go about doing it?

If there is any other way other than custom overlay, please let me know of the same as well.

Note that there is already a grid layer which i am using the information for. I have attached the sample image for reference purpose and the grids shown in the image is the layer i am using as reference for custom overlay.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Because the Custom Overlay creation dialog only offers one label field, a quick and dirty solution is to create a custom overlay for each axis, and add both grids to the map document.

When you create a new Custom Overlay, select the appropriate label field for the horizontal axis in the Custom Overlay tab, then deselect the Left and Right radio buttons in the Labels tab to hide the labels on the axis you DON'T want labeled with that data. (I usually make the same deselection in the Axes tab to get rid of the ticks on that axis as well, but it isn't necessary, as the ticks from both grids should just draw over each other if you leave them on.)

Create a second Custom Overlay for the vertical axis using the appropriate label field, deselecting the Top and Bottom radio buttons in the Label (and Axes) tab(s).

When you add both Custom Overlays to the map, each axis will be labelled properly.